# What does pandas wide_to_long IndexError mean?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm having trouble converting my data from wide format to long format using `pd.wide_to_long()` method. The error reads `IndexError: Too many levels: Index has only 1 level, not 2`

My code:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data/data.csv', index_col=False)
print(df)


df.reset_index(inplace=True,drop=True)
df['ID'] = df.index
pd.wide_to_long(df, ['OT_', 'NT_'], i='ID', j=['MISS', 'HIT', 'CR', 'FA']).reset_index().rename(columns={'OT_': 'OT', 'NT_': 'NT'})
```

CSV (its just junk data):

```
PID,OT_MISS,OT_HIT,OT_CR,OT_FA,NT_MISS,NT_HIT,NT_CR,NT_FA
111,0.1,0.23,0.56,0.11,0.9,1.0,0.92,0.68
121,0.1,0.23,0.56,0.11,0.9,1.0,0.92,0.68
212,0.1,0.23,0.56,0.11,0.9,1.0,0.92,0.68
321,0.1,0.23,0.56,0.11,0.9,1.0,0.92,0.68
423,0.1,0.23,0.56,0.11,0.9,1.0,0.92,0.68
534,0.1,0.23,0.56,0.11,0.9,1.0,0.92,0.68
621,0.1,0.23,0.56,0.11,0.9,1.0,0.92,0.68
721,0.1,0.23,0.56,0.11,0.9,1.0,0.92,0.68
812,0.1,0.23,0.56,0.11,0.9,1.0,0.92,0.68
922,0.1,0.23,0.56,0.11,0.9,1.0,0.92,0.68
```

Answer (score 0):

In panda, you can use melt() function to transform the data from wide to long format as follows:

```
df2=pd.melt(df, ['OT_', 'NT_'], i='ID', j=['MISS', 'HIT', 'CR', 'FA']).reset_index().rename(columns={'OT_': 'OT', 'NT_': 'NT'})
```

Comment: I tried your code and got a different error `TypeError: melt() got an unexpected keyword argument 'i'`

Answer (score 0):

- The issue is [pandas.wide_to_long](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html) didn't properly recognize the suffixes, `i` should be `'PID'` not `'ID'`, and `j` is supposed to be a string.
- `'\w+'` is a regular expression to get one or more word characters

```py
import pandas as pd

df2 = pd.wide_to_long(df, ['OT', 'NT'], i='PID', j='stubs', sep='_', suffix='\w+')

print(df2)

             OT    NT
PID stubs            
111 MISS   0.10  0.90
121 MISS   0.10  0.90
212 MISS   0.10  0.90
321 MISS   0.10  0.90
423 MISS   0.10  0.90
534 MISS   0.10  0.90
621 MISS   0.10  0.90
721 MISS   0.10  0.90
812 MISS   0.10  0.90
922 MISS   0.10  0.90
111 HIT    0.23  1.00
121 HIT    0.23  1.00
212 HIT    0.23  1.00
321 HIT    0.23  1.00
423 HIT    0.23  1.00
534 HIT    0.23  1.00
621 HIT    0.23  1.00
721 HIT    0.23  1.00
812 HIT    0.23  1.00
922 HIT    0.23  1.00
111 CR     0.56  0.92
121 CR     0.56  0.92
212 CR     0.56  0.92
321 CR     0.56  0.92
423 CR     0.56  0.92
534 CR     0.56  0.92
621 CR     0.56  0.92
721 CR     0.56  0.92
812 CR     0.56  0.92
922 CR     0.56  0.92
111 FA     0.11  0.68
121 FA     0.11  0.68
212 FA     0.11  0.68
321 FA     0.11  0.68
423 FA     0.11  0.68
534 FA     0.11  0.68
621 FA     0.11  0.68
721 FA     0.11  0.68
812 FA     0.11  0.68
922 FA     0.11  0.68
```